# App Configure - Module, not configured correctly? Help Divio

Tags: django, python-3.7, divio

I'm using the Divio Platform to deploy a simple Django application and no matter i've done with this namespace, it's throwing an error.

I have tried adding an **init**.py file in the folder, as well as out of the folder and i'm quite confused to be honest as I can't think how else my application would work.  I've even tried renaming the folder, adjusting in main urls but nothing seems to be working.  I have already reviewed the pep420 to see if it would help, also django but I think the issue is more towards Divio as folder structure goes like this. Might I know this is the first time im using this platform.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Voyage application #
    path('/app', include('app.urls')),
] + aldryn_addons.urls.patterns() + i18n_patterns(
    # add your own i18n patterns here
    *aldryn_addons.urls.i18n_patterns()  # MUST be the last entry!
)
```

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app module <module 'app' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['/app/app', './app']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute`

Comment: Can you show the project structure that you are using? Is your own application called ``app``?